# How much time does Realm take for a write transaction to perform an Object add?

Tags: ios, datasource, realm

I have a collection view with Realm datasource. If I add or update an Realm Object in a write transaction then immediately try to refetch from the datasource, of course the new write is not finished. Thus what I'm doing currently is adding a 0.1 second delay before refetching.

My question is, are there better approaches? If not, how much time (magnitude of 0.0001 sec or 0.01 sec etc) does a normal Realm write > add transaction take? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're not seeing the updates to a Realm file straight away, you can call `refresh` on the `RLMRealm` / `Realm` object to manually force a refresh.

Normally changes are updated across all Realm objects on all threads on the next iteration of the run loop (Which you would also achieve by introducing a time delay like you have above!), but calling `refresh` will cause that version of the Realm object to update before the current iteration of the run loop has completed.

Comment: Thanks @Tim - based on your explanation I found approaches to run on next loop: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7096203/how-to-call-a-method-a-s-a-p-but-at-earliest-in-the-next-run-loop-iteration.
You said "Normally", so there are exceptions from time to time? I can see that for large NSData. Any other cases?

Comment: No problems! Yeah, you can choose to disable this autorefresh behaviour if you want, which then explicitly requires calling `refresh` on a Realm object in order to get the latest updates.

Comment: So when autorefresh is on (by default), it's guaranteed it will be refreshed on the next run pass? Even for large NSData? Just want to make it clear :)

Comment: Yeah. :) Realm lazy loads properties when you load them, so it won't actually load the `NSData` until you actually call it. In any case, if it's a concern, I'd recommend testing that out to ensure it works with your app's implementation. :)